# Проблема с Laravel Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

Не получается удалить запись из БД используя Ajax. CRUD без Ajax работает.

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    @include('errors')

    <div class="pull-right">
        <a href="{{route('item.create')}}" class="btn btn-info">Add new</a>
    </div>
    <div class=" table-responsive">

        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>N</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Parent_id</th>
                <th>Show Edit Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach($items as $item)

                <tbody>
                <th>{{$item->id}}</th>
                <th>{{$item->name}}</th>
                <th>{{$item->parent_id}}</th>
                <th>

                    {{Form::open()}}
                    {{Form::button('Delete',['type'=>'submit','class'=>'btn btn-block btn-danger send'])}}
                    {{Form::close()}}
                </th>
                </tbody>
            @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>

    <p><b></b>
    </p>
    <script src="{{asset('js/delAjax.js')}}"></script>
@endsection
```

Код delAjax.js (в базе есть запись с id 13)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('.send').on('submit',function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'delete',
            url:'{{route("ajax"}}',
            data:{id:13},
            success:function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Контролер

```
public function ajax($id)
    {

        Test::findOrFail($id)->delete();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Item deleted']);
    }
```

Маршрут

```
Route::delete('/ajax/','MainController@ajax')->name('ajax');
```

Консоль выдает

```
CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token
(anonymous) @ app.js:13953
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:13896
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:13881
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:63
(anonymous) @ app.js:66
app.js:36551 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app
```

Хотя вроде бы токены есть.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <script src="http://192.168.10.10:2222/js/app.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="Y0UqBwRALqmRw3dfrKEuKoz4gURVkl0tHxvacRJx">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.10.10:2222/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.10.10:2222/css/tree.css">
    <!-- Optional JavaScript  for treview-->



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.10.10:2222/css/bootstrap-treeview.min.cs">

    <title>BlackSeaCorporation</title>
    <!-- token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="Y0UqBwRALqmRw3dfrKEuKoz4gURVkl0tHxvacRJx">


</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">B_S_C</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-fill" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/table">Admin table <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">

            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Sigh in
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add Item</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Add with AJAX</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Show all</a>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="http://192.168.10.10:2222/search">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="s">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">


    <div class="pull-right">
        <a href="http://192.168.10.10:2222/item/create" class="btn btn-info">Add new</a>
    </div>
    <div class=" table-responsive">

        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>N</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Parent_id</th>
                <th>Show Edit Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

                <tbody>
                <th>5</th>
                <th>AudiQ7</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>

                    <form method="POST" action="http://192.168.10.10:2222/index1" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Y0UqBwRALqmRw3dfrKEuKoz4gURVkl0tHxvacRJx">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger send">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </th>
                </tbody>

                <tbody>
                <th>14</th>
                <th>Samsung</th>
                <th>2</th>
                <th>

                    <form method="POST" action="http://192.168.10.10:2222/index1" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Y0UqBwRALqmRw3dfrKEuKoz4gURVkl0tHxvacRJx">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger send">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </th>
                </tbody>

                <tbody>
                <th>15</th>
                <th>Audi</th>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>

                    <form method="POST" action="http://192.168.10.10:2222/index1" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Y0UqBwRALqmRw3dfrKEuKoz4gURVkl0tHxvacRJx">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger send">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </th>
                </tbody>

                <tbody>
                <th>17</th>
                <th>Yuriy Peresypko</th>
                <th>3</th>
                <th>

                    <form method="POST" action="http://192.168.10.10:2222/index1" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Y0UqBwRALqmRw3dfrKEuKoz4gURVkl0tHxvacRJx">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger send">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </th>
                </tbody>

                <tbody>
                <th>18</th>
                <th>Number1</th>
                <th>1</th>
                <th>

                    <form method="POST" action="http://192.168.10.10:2222/index1" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Y0UqBwRALqmRw3dfrKEuKoz4gURVkl0tHxvacRJx">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger send">Send</button>
                    </form>
                </th>
                </tbody>
                    </table>
    </div>

    <p><b></b>
    </p>
    <script src="http://192.168.10.10:2222/js/delAjax.js"></script>
    <div id="treeview"></div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте передать токен вместе с параметрами запроса в свойстве `data`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

    $('.send').on('submit',function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'delete',
            url:'{{route("ajax"}}',
            data:{
                id: 13,
                _token: _token
            },
            success:function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Попробовал - результат не изменился :-((((

Comment: выведите входящие параметры в `action` (`dd($request)`) предварительно отключив middleware csrfTokenVerify

Comment: Помогло. Продолжаем работать. СПС

Comment: что именно помогло? то что вы отключили проверку на токен или токен все таки удалось передать?

Comment: получилось передать токен. скорее всего проблема была с app.js Подключил с cdn -заработало. но осадок остался: мистика